# Multiple form error handling with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-hook-form

i need to maintain error object of every form in single object which is released by react-hook-form, any ideas?

form 1 error object i get

```
{
firstname: {
message: "required field",
type: "required"
}
}
```

form 2 error object i get

```
{
email: {
message: "required field",
type: "required"
}
}
```

expected result:

```
{
form1: {
firstname: {
message: "required field",
type: "required"
}
},
form2: {
email: {
message: "required field",
type: "required"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please use like your multiple validations:

```
const {
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    handleFocus,
    data,
    setData,
    errors,
    setErrors,
    handleBlur,
  } = useForm({
    initialValues: { firstname: "", email: "" },
    ref: ref, // Your Ref Definded
    validations: {
      firstname: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter firstname",
        },
      },
      lastname: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter lastname",
        },
      },
      username: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter username",
        },
        custom: {
          isValid: (value) =>
            value && value.length >= 3 && value.length <= 25 ? true : false,
          message: "Username must be between 3 to 25 characters",
        },
      },
      otpfield: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter either Email id or Mobile No",
        },
        pattern: {
          value:
            /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})|([0-9]{10})+$/,
          message: "Please enter either Email id or Mobile No",
        },
      },
      password: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter password",
        },
        pattern: {
          value:
            "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$",
          message:
            "Minimum 8 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character",
        },
        custom: {
          isValid: (value) =>
            value && value.length >= 8 && value.length <= 16 ? true : false,
          message: "Password must be between 8 to 16 characters",
        },
      },
      confirmpassword: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter confirm password",
        },
        custom: {
          isValid: (value) => value && value === data.password,
          message: "Password and confirm password must be same",
        },
      },
      email: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter your email address",
        },
        pattern: {
          value: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/,
          message: "Please enter valid email address",
        },
      },
      mobile: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter mobile number",
        },
        pattern: {
          value: /^[0-9]+$/,
          message: "Please enter numbers only",
        },
        custom: {
          isValid: (value) =>
            value && value.length >= 8 && value.length <= 12 ? true : false,
          message: "Mobile number must be between 8 to 12 digits",
        },
      },
      address1: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter address",
        },
      },
      countrycode: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter country code",
        },
        pattern: {
          value: /^\+?(\d+)/,
          message: "Please enter proper country code",
        },
      },
      country: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please select country",
        },
      },
      state: {
         required: {
           value: true,
           message: "Please select state",
         },
      },
      city: {
         required: {
           value: true,
           message: "Please select city",
         },
      },
      areacode: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter areacode",
        },
        pattern: {
          value: /^[0-9]+$/,
          message: "Please enter numbers only",
        },
      },
      occupation: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please enter occupation",
        },
      },
      checkbox: {
        required: {
          value: true,
          message: "Please agree the terms and conditions",
        },
      },
    },
    onSubmit: () => console.log(data)
  });
```